# how to call a databricks notebook from an external python notebook

Tags: python, rest, azure-databricks

I want to create a python notebook on my desktop that pass an input to another notebook in databricks, and then return the output of the databricks notebook. For example, my local python file will pass a string into a databricks notebook, which will reverse the string and then output the result back to my local python file. What would be the best way to achieve this?

[https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/python-api.html#:~:text=In%20your%20Python%20code%20file,get%20the%20environment%20variable%20values.&text=Import%20the%20ApiClient%20class%20from,with%20the%20Databricks%20REST%20API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/python-api.html#:%7E:text=In%20your%20Python%20code%20file,get%20the%20environment%20variable%20values.&text=Import%20the%20ApiClient%20class%20from,with%20the%20Databricks%20REST%20API).

I used the Rest API detailed in this link. I added my workspace instance https://adb-################.##.azuredatabricks.net and created a token, which is working now.

Edit:
When I try to create a new run, I get this error. Is my json formatted incorrectly or am I missing something else? Thanks

```
import os
from databricks_cli.sdk.api_client import ApiClient
from databricks_cli.clusters.api import ClusterApi

os.environ['DATABRICKS_HOST'] = "https://adb-################.##.azuredatabricks.net/"
os.environ['DATABRICKS_TOKEN'] = "token-value" 

api_client = ApiClient(host=os.getenv('DATABRICKS_HOST'), token=os.getenv('DATABRICKS_TOKEN'))

runJson = """
        {
        "name": "test job",
        "max_concurrent_runs": 1,
        "tasks": [
            {
            "task_key": "test",
            "description": "test",
            "notebook_task":
                {
                "notebook_path": "/Users/user@domain.com/api_test"
                },
            "existing_cluster_id": "cluster_name",
            "timeout_seconds": 3600,
            "max_retries": 3,
            "retry_on_timeout": true
            }
            ]
        }
        """

runs_api = RunsApi(api_client)
runs_api.submit_run(runJson)


Error:
    Response from server: 
 { 'error_code': 'MALFORMED_REQUEST',
  'message': 'Invalid JSON given in the body of the request - expected a map'}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that you are using?

Comment: see edit. i basically just used the same format in the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AttributeError: type object 'Retry' has no attribute 'DEFAULT_METHOD_WHITELIST'

AS per this [Discussion](https://community.databricks.com/s/feed/0D58Y0000AGrUWvSQN)

**Root cause:**

- On 5/3/23, the library was updated: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.2/changelog.html#id1
- The DEFAULT_METHOD_WHITELIST parameter for the retry class is absent from the library's most recent versions.

**The workaround and possible solution:**

> - Downgrade to this version**urllib3==1.26.15**  or you can directly add this to requirements.txt.
> - you can try following commands to uninstall and install urlib3 with specific version.
>
> ```py
> pip install -U databricks-cli
> pip uninstall -y urllib3
> pip install urllib3==1.26.15
> ```

Comment: this fixed the connection issue, thanks. I am getting an error now when trying to create a new job run.

Comment: You can post new Qs with your error details. The community will help.

Comment: i figured it was part of the same problem so i did an edit instead of reposting a copy, but i guess i can do that too